# Error While updating the accessdb using python

Tags: python, ms-access

I am trying to update one of the column in the ACCESSDB using Python and the query is given below.

```
with conn.cursor() as crsr:
    crsr.execute("UPDATE table1 a SET a.Number = (SELECT Number FROM Table2 WHERE condt= a.condt)")
```

I am getting the below error

Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Operation must use an updateable query. (-3035) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Please let me know what is the mistake here.

Comment: Can't you just join the tables on the condt fields?

Comment: Are you referring to the Access file correctly? Do you have the right folder permissions? With this little info from you it's a bit wild guessing.